# Qwt turn off scientific notation for axis labels

Tags: c++, qt, qwt, scientific-notation

By default, `Qwt` displays large numbers on the axis in scientific notation:

[image: axis labels in scientific notation]

For my application, I'd really like to turn this off OR reformat the labels. Looking through the [class documentation](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/annotated.html), it doesn't seem like any of the `QwtScale` classes have an option for this. Can this behavior be implemented by deriving a new class? If so, which class should it be derived from and which members would need to be overloaded?

Comment: Just take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587571/change-axis-ticks-and-label-to-switch-between-millimeter-and-inch-in-qwt-plot You can override scale draw class like I did.

Comment: One additional comment for your special case, overriding `QwtScaleDraw::label(double)` in your own derived `QwtScaleDraw` class should be sufficient.

Comment: @bkausbk your answer actually helped me solve a couple problems, I wish I could have upvoted it once for each!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to bkausbk, I was able to come up with this modified `QwtScaleDraw`:

```
class QScaleDraw : public QwtScaleDraw
{
public:

    explicit QScaleDraw(bool enableScientificNotation = false)
    : m_scientificNotationEnabled(enableScientificNotation)
    {

    }

    virtual QwtText label(double value) const override
    {
        if (m_scientificNotationEnabled)
        {
            return QwtScaleDraw::label(value);
        } 
        else
        {
            return QwtText(QString::number(value, 'f', 0));
        }
    }

private:

    bool    m_scientificNotationEnabled;                                                

};
```

then to use it, you do something like:

```
QwtPlot myplot;
myplot->setAxisScaleDraw(xBottom, new QScaleDraw);
```

## Result

[image: axis labels without scientific notation]

Comment: good answer remove the semi colon from "virtual QwtText label(double value) const override;" though